# Adding AWS LoadBalancer to Service using AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I am trying to add an AWS ELB to a ECS Cluster Service using AWS CLI. I am using the following command:

`aws ecs create-service --service-name ${SERVICE_NAME} --desired-count 1 --task-definition launch-test-app --load-balancers targetGroupArn=arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:NNNNNNNNNNNN:loadbalancer/app/bw-test/edfe7f7c15e40d56,containerName=launch-test-app,containerPort=8080 --role arn:aws:iam::NNNNNNNNNNNN:role/service-role/bw-metering-role --cluster ${CLUSTER} --region ${REGION}`

The Role 'bw-metering-role' has following policies attached:

- AmazonEC2ContainerServiceFullAccess
- AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role

And the Role also has following Trust Relationship:

`{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": [
          "ecs.amazonaws.com",
          "ec2.amazonaws.com"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}`

But still I am getting following error while executing the above AWS CLI command:

`An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the CreateService operation: Unable to assume role and validate the specified targetGroupArn. Please verify that the ECS service role being passed has the proper permissions.`

I have searched and found some solutions, but with no positive result.

Comment: The service should only need `AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role` and you generally don’t need to specify role explicitly, since it will automatically assume the role `AWSServiceRoleForECS`, which is created in your account when you create the ECS cluster.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After going through AWS documentation, I found that for classic load balancers we should provide the following details (loadBalancerName):

`--load-balancers loadBalancerName=bwce-lb,containerName=launch-test-app,containerPort=8080`

And for application load balancers (which is my case), we should provide following details (targetGroupArn):

`--load-balancers targetGroupArn=arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:750037626691:targetgroup/default/85fd830384028e21,containerName=launch-test-app,containerPort=8080`

The problem in my previous input values was that, I was providing the LoadBalancer ARN in the 'targetGroupArn' field instead of providing the TargetGroupARN. Once I fixed the traget group ARN issue, it started working fine.